# How can I keep my team's enthusiasm

Tags: management, team, project-management, time-management, student

I am a young entrepreneur with a brand new start up. I am still at school and so are my developers. The thing is one of my developer left the project because he couldn't spare enough time to work on it efficiently. We are all working
fulltime in a job for the summer and part-time on the project. We spend most of our free time working on the start up to do as much as possible before the university start. We also want to keep working part-time on it during school.

**Edit**: We agreed to work around 5 to 10 hours every week on the project each. Some week can be less than 5 and others can be more than 10 as long as everyone reach their deadline on time. I thought this would be the fairest way to go.

**My question is** : Since I don't have a lot of knowledge on team management. I would like to know how could I keep everyone excited about the project and prevent them from quitting? I fear they will think they won't be able to manage their time for the project and school. Personally I am 100% confident they will be able to do it since they are really talented student/programmer. It won't be easy, of course, but I believe it's feasible.

Note : I didn't ask this question on the startup section since I think it is more related to the workplace/Team managing.

Please pardon my lack of knowledge on this subject and my English.

Comment: What incentive do they get by working for you(or with you) ? Do you have a good development plan and measurable milestones and did you take into account conflicting schedules of each of your team when planing the development ?

Comment: Well right now they get the same reward as I get which means: the satisfaction of being part of a new and promising startup and the possibility of making money with it (There is already interest from multiple clients). We do have a development plan for which we considered the unexpected such as school project, sickness, etc.

Comment: @MasterD.C Making money with it through wages or equity?

Comment: Sorry I should have specified. They would get equity and money relatively to the amount of equity they have. Since we all do pretty much the same work this looks like the best way to go for now.

Comment: Do you have downtime reserved for having fun, relaxing, enjoying the college experience etc.?

Comment: Yes I count all of those in the unexpected. Since we are all college student and also massive nerds, I did expect that sometimes my team and I would like to just relax and have fun. I am not a very demanding "Boss", if you can even call it like that, but I do like to push my team to work their hardest and to waste as little time as possible when it's time to work. (Like every good team leader should do in my opinion.)

Comment: Fun, relaxing, and enjoying the college experience should not be "unexpected". If you don't plan in some vacations you may be tempted to skip them, and end up with massive burnout.

Comment: I meant unexpected as for something that is not already planned. I usually don't know what I am doing for the weekend before Thursday night or even Friday. That is what I meant by unexpected. But I do get the idea of planning vacations. The only problem is that, like I said, we have pretty wild schedules since we are college students.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic here. Could work on Productivity Stack Exchange

Answer (score 5):

> Personally I am 100% confident they will be able to do it since they
>   are really talented student/programmer.

Do you realize how clueless this sounds?

Computer Science projects in schools are usually well defined. They don't have much UI. They're nothing more than bare-bone prototypes. And even if the student doing those projects is super talented, you can rest assured that he spends way more than 10 man hours a week on them.

In any case, before you can answer your question on motivation, you'll need to read this book called [Mythical Man Month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mythical_Man-Month).

For your partnership question, you and your potential partners will need to read this book [Partnership Charter](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0738208981) written by a mediator who knows how partnerships usually break apart, so he has some pretty good pragmatic advice on what to do before you set up a partnership.

Drafting a partnership charter will help with the motivation part as well. Not everyone has the same intent/motivation for starting a business and you'll need to find out if those motivations/goals are even compatible with each other's.

Comment: As a student who has worked with them for multiple projects I can assure you that UI are highly important in school projects and are in every cours I have ever taken. And about the 10 hour of work I approve that they spend more than 10 hours but the time we gave us is more or so a way for us to keep a constant workflow. But I will go ahead and get those books thank you sir.

Comment: I wasn't clear on the type of school you were attending. In any case, reading your other comments, I am glad that you know this kind of development work is probably going to take way more than 5 to 10 hours a week.

Answer (score 2):

These people are basically volunteers, this isn't a feasible way of doing a project that takes any length of time. 5 or 10 hours a week doesn't show any commitment. It's a hobby.

Motivation is hard to achieve without discipline. You won't get that sort of commitment from school kids who aren't being paid.

You have too many people involved. You'd be better off with one person doing 20 hours, than 4 doing 5 hours. So cut it down to the really self-motivated people with a vested interest in the start up.

Keep the hierarchy as small and simple as possible. I've seen lots of startups fail just because too many fingers were in the pie, and no clear leadership.

Comment: With no written agreement in place, cutting down the size of the team has potential to blow up in the OPs face unless they can agree to buy out terms with the outgoing parties.

Comment: @Myles 10% of zero is zero, there's the payoff, you get nowhere in a startup if you're not ruthless enough. I know you're going to talk about legal action... but you cross that bridge when you need to, the primary concern is getting up and running and making money. Then stomping on anyone who tries to take it from you.

Comment: Not thinking legal.  I'm thinking trying to drop half of the group may lose you the whole group.  Advertising that 10% of zero is zero will not do good things for retention of the ones you want to keep and drastically upsetting the group dynamic may have the same effect.  These are college kids not seasoned professionals.

Comment: if you lose the whole group, then they have no commitment to the project, best to find out now... but in reality you usually lose most of them before it kicks off, leaving just a couple. Most successful startups with too many people go through this. Attrition is high until things settle into efficiency.

Comment: 3 persons is too many?  I think Myles is right cutting down the size of the team is not the best solution but giving a clear understanding of what everyone will get at the end will help. Like I said to @Stephan Branczyk the time we gave us per week is more or so a way for us to keep a constant workflow. I already know they will do alot more than that. Giving a minimum and a maximum make is so that the person who can't give more than is the limite we gave us won't feel bad for not working as much as the other one doing 20 hours. If they do more it's their problem.

Comment: Then why are you asking the question? I've been in more than one startup, never seen what you describe work. In fact most startups I know about have failed for the simple reason that there was too many people. All doing whatever they felt like doing because, why not, it's not like their paycheque depends on it. Responsibilities have to be defined, discipline has to be enforced.

Comment: @Kilisi My question is about what can I do to keep the spirit of my team up and what to do to make sure they don't feel like they can't do the work I ask them to do (To not make them feel overworked). I really don't see how firing people from the team is a good way to KEEP them IN the team. I think you're missing the point of my question by a lot here.

Answer (score 1):

> They would get equity and money relatively to the amount of equity
>   they have. Since we all do pretty much the same work this looks like
>   the best way to go for now.

When paying for work today with promises of tomorrow there are a couple of things to remember:

- Document and share concrete progress: Realistically they are working on something that is potentially worthless.  If this thing falls apart they can't go after you for backpay like they could an employer.  You need to keep their confidence high that they are going to see fruit from their labors.
- Ensure that "same work for the same amount of equity" is in fact perceived as the same work: A team member under contributing can kill morale.  If I put in 100 productive hours to their 50 productive and 50 goofing around and we get the same equity I would be upset.  Perception of uneven workload is bad for your team so periodically feel out for how the team is viewing each others contributions.  This can be tough because not every feature is feasible so someone hitting a couple of dead ends can be seen as not contributing as much.
- Stay friends: Be sure that you are hanging out outside of work and that those hangouts don't turn into work.  This strengthens the group dynamic.

Comment: We haven't really signed any contract yet on which percentage of shares everyone should have. We have verbally agreed that we should wait a bit and separate share depending on what amount of work everyone as put in ("contributions check" like ou have suggested). Is it a good idea? Should I define shares and specify that the percentage could change depending on their work ("contributions check" like ou have suggested)? I think this might be more depressing to see your share being cut down like that for the person who is working less.

Comment: @MasterD.C These things should be decided in writing before people start investing significant time into it.  Contribution checks can be formalized as a regular part of the process or can be an "as needed" clause but should definitely be defined in writing as early as possible.  I would strongly recommend migrating this question to the Startups SE.  Since you are paying in equity, the challenges for keeping this team running are quite different from a regular workplace.